# DSP on Beaglebone

Tags: signal-processing, beagleboard

I have a Beaglebone running Ubuntu. We want to continuously sample from 3 on-board ATD converters at 100KS/s, and every window of samples we will run a cross correlation DSP algorithm. Once we find a correlation value above a threshold, we will send the value to a PC.

My concern is the process scheduling in Ubuntu. If our process gets swapped out and an ATD sample becomes available during this time, the process will miss the sample. We need to ensure that our process will capture every sample and save it in memory.

With this being said, is there a way to trigger interrupts on the Beaglebone so that if an ATD sample is ready, the sample will be saved in the memory of our program *even if the program does not have the processor at the time*?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to trigger the EDMA or use the PRUSS. Probably best to ask on beagleboard@googlegroups.com. There isn't a DSP per-se on the BeagleBone.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an answer to your question, but hopefully it explains how the process works. Since you didn't mention what hardware you are running for AD conversion, maybe this is the best that can be done:

With audio hardware, which faces the same problem, the solution comes from the hardware and the drivers working together: whenever the hardware has filled up enough of the buffer it signals the driver (via an interrupt or some similar mechanism). In some cases, it's also possible that the driver polls the hardware or something like that, but that's a less efficient solution, and I'm not sure anyone does it that way anymore (maybe on cheaper hardware?). From there, the driver process may call right into the end-user process, or it may simply mark the relevant end-user process as "runnable". Either way, control needs to be transferred to the end user process.

For that to happen, the end user process must be running at a higher priority than anything else occupying the CPUs at that moment. To guarantee that your process will always be first in the queue, you can run it at a high priority, with the appropriate permissions, you can even run in very high priorities.

The time it takes for the top priority process to go from runnable to running is sometimes called the "latency" of the OS, though I am sure there's a more specific technical term. The latency of Linux is on the order of 1 ms, but since it's not a "hard" real-time OS, this is not a guarantee. If this is too long to handle your chunks of data, you may have to buffer some of it in your driver.